# How to crop an image selected with django-filer in django admin

Tags: django, image, crop, django-filer

I use [django-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer) to manage images. How can I crop and image after selecting one for a FilerImageField?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet that combines django-filer and [django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping). Just use `CroppableFilerImageField` instead of `FilerImageField` your models.

Note that you still have to press "Save and continue editing" after selecting the image to be able to crop.

```
from django.conf import settings

from filer import settings as filer_settings
from filer.fields.image import (
    AdminImageWidget, AdminImageFormField, FilerImageField,
)
from filer.models import File


class CroppableImageWidget(AdminImageWidget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value:
            file_obj = File.objects.get(pk=value)
            attrs = attrs or {}
            attrs.update({
                'class': 'crop-thumb',
                'data-thumbnail-url':
                    file_obj.thumbnails['admin_sidebar_preview'],
                'data-field-name': name,
                'data-org-width': file_obj.width,
                'data-org-height': file_obj.height,
            })

        return super().render(name, value, attrs)

    class Media:
        js = (
            filer_settings.FILER_STATICMEDIA_PREFIX + 'js/popup_handling.js',
            getattr(settings, 'JQUERY_URL',
                    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'),
            "image_cropping/js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js",
            "image_cropping/image_cropping.js",
        )
        css = {'all': ("image_cropping/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css",)}


class CroppableFormField(AdminImageFormField):
    widget = CroppableImageWidget


class CroppableFilerImageField(FilerImageField):
    default_form_class = CroppableFormField
```

Comment: Hi @petri-lehtinen Could you please update your answer based on the latest version. This doesn't seem to work now